# Pinging someone at an interval discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am making a bot and want it to ping a user every ten minutes. Here is what I have right now

```
@client.event
while True:
  channel = client.get_channel(717346417592762457)
  await message.channel.send(<@!561464966427705374>)
  time.sleep(600)
```

But this results in a lot of errors.

Comment: If that's a string, it needs to be in quotes.

Comment: I get two errors now. ```Expected function or class declaration after decorator``` and ```"await" allowed only within async function```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy way to do it would be to use discord's [`tasks extension`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html). You can easily set the amount of time for each loop. The only main drawback is that the loop restarts every time your bot restarts, or rather everytime you run the command, in this example. In the example below, I added the method to start the loop in a command, but you can have it start in an [`on_ready` event](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.event) or similar.

```py
# New Import
from discord.ext import tasks, commands

# ... Other code ...

@tasks.loop(minutes=10) # @tasks.loop(seconds=600) <-- does the same amount of time
async def ping_loop():
    channel = client.get_channel(717346417592762457)
    await channel.send("<@!561464966427705374>")
    # 1. Don't use message.channel, as you only defined channel and this isn't an event
    # 2. As mentioned by Tim Roberts in the comments
    #    add speech marks to your send() since it's a string

# somewhere else in your code
@client.command()
async def loop(ctx):
    try:
        ping_loop.start() # start the loop if it isn't currently running
        await ctx.send("Started pinging <@!561464966427705374>")
    except: # happens if the loop is already running
        ping_loop.cancel() # if so, cancel the loop
        await ctx.send("Stopped pinging <@!561464966427705374>")
```

[image: Image of above being tested]

Answer (score 0):

For the specific errors you mentioned:

```py
@client.event
async def somefunction(ctx): 
# you need to define a function to call (pass to discord.py)
# also the function has to be async, for the usage of `await`
while True:
  channel = client.get_channel(717346417592762457)
  await message.channel.send(<@!561464966427705374>) 
  # not sure if you can mention user like this
  await asyncio.sleep(600)
  # time.sleep(600) # prefer non-blocking asyncio sleep. make sure `asyncio` is imported
```

To mention a user, you need to first get user with

```py
user_instance = ctx.guild.get_member(YOUR_USER_discord_id)
```

Note: You may need to enable the privilege to use the `.get_member()` function. If you have not enabled it yet, just follow the instructions in the exception.

Then you can sent message with

```py
await ctx.send(f"THE_TEXT_YOU_WANT_TO_SPAM {user_instance.mention}!")
```

Also, if you are using it in a bot command like me, you may want to add some validation, so that not everyone can cast/invoke the command. I did this with `has_role()`:

```py
@commands.has_role(YOUR_ROLE_ID_THAT_CAN_CAST_THIS_COMMAND)
```

So in the end, it looks like this:

```py
@bot.command('name': 'spam', 'help':'use at @ to mention a user')
@commands.has_role(YOUR_ROLE_ID_THAT_CAN_CAST_THIS_COMMAND)
async def spamMention(ctx, spam_duration_second: int = 3):
    user_instance = ctx.guild.get_member(YOUR_USER_discord_id)
    for cntr in range(spam_duration_second):
        await ctx.send(f"THE_TEXT_YOU_WANT_TO_SPAM {user_instance.mention}!")        
        await asyncio.sleep(THE_INTERVAL_YOU_WANT_IN_SECOND)
    return
```

It's part of my code so I know it works (my python version: 3.7.9).

Comment: Few questions, what does ```spam_duration_second: int = 3``` do and other thing  in the line ```for cntr in range(spamtime)``` I don't see that you have defined spam time anywhere.. Any fixes?

Comment: Sorry, I modified the code to upload it here. They should be the same variable. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: No problem. But I am getting ```raise TypeError('event registered must be a coroutine function')
TypeError: event registered must be a coroutine function``` Any idea why?

Comment: You mean the first part of the answer? It seems that you are missing `async` keyword before `def`-ining a function.

Comment: I have included it

Comment: can I see the code, please? It should be clearly written where the error occured.